# problems to create DataGrid with XHR

Tags: datagrid, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to build a DataGrid using XHR, but the Grid is not being created correctly, I saw many examples and did my based on what I found on the internet but without success ...

what am I doing wrong?

my dojo:

```
var a = dojo.xhrGet({
                                                url : "/dojo/pix/StatusXml",
                                                handlesAs: "xml",
                                                preventCache: true,
                                                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
                                // mimetype: "application/xml"
                                        });


                a.addCallback(function(myXml) {
                        var grid = dijit.byId("grid");
                // var gridStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:{items: myXml} });
                        var gridStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data:{items: myXml} });
                        alert("myxml: \n"+ myXml +" \n gridStore: \n"+gridStore);

          grid.setStore(gridStore);
                        grid.refresh();

                });
```

Gid the result in the message that appears is "sorry, an error occurred" 
[enter link description here](http://postimage.org/image/1gzxz6r1g/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `xml` as the `handleAs` value of `dojo.xhrGet` function, the response data will be converted to a XML DOM object. But `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` is expecting to get a JSON object as the data format.

So you can either use `dojox.data.XmlStore` as the grid's store or convert the XML DOM object to JSON data manually. Actually it's not required to use XHR here, because `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` and `dojox.data.XmlStore` can use URL as the data source and they will handle the data retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

dojox.data.XmlStore not retrieve data from the servlet by XMLRequest ... only data from a file